# Can the access token returned to an AngularJS app be used by an attacker?

Tags: keycloak

We are looking into integrating keycloak to protect a front end AngularJS application which is served by a nodeJS application and also makes API requests to this server.

Having watched some tutorials, we see we need to use the javascript adapter for the AngularJS app to handle the user auth flow, and then protect our nodeJS application using the bearer only strategy, ensuring angularJS outgoing requests to our Node application contains an Auth header with the bearer token value present.

I have a question\concern about the way in which the token is being served back to the client as I can see it gets saved into a cookie which I assume is what the javascript adapter reads from in order for us to be able to write the Auth header into subsequent requests from the angular app.

My question is can this token value be easily read from the browser cookie and used maliciously by an attacker trying to make api requests?

Am I right in thinking it would be highly unlikely since the attacker would need to know the secret which is stored on the nodeJS side?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to know the client secret to use access token. That secret is used only to issue access token. If someone has your unexpired access token, then that someone will be able to use your identity until token expires. But you can minimise the possibility of the stolen access token by using https, httponly cookies. Also, you can use a short token lifetime (for example 5 minute). But then you will need to implement refresh tokens; otherwise, the user will need to re-login whenever access token expires.

I think the proper implementation is not trivial. I recommend using of some reverse auth-proxy, which will handle authorization and authentification in front of your app. Tip: https://github.com/gambol99/keycloak-proxy